# Como posso importar arquivos de fonte de texto no Tkinter em Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu quero saber como posso importar o arquivo de fonte usando o Tkinter, para que não ocorra problemas de fonte em outros sistemas. Por que se eu enviar para um amigo, ele não vai conseguir ver a fonte selecionada, caso ele não tenha a fonte instalada no sistema dele. É possível? Se sim, como eu poderia fazer isso? Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso, você pode criar um executável do seu projeto com **PyInstaller**, ele irá criar um executável para roda em qualquer maquina, mesmo que não tenha instalado o Python.

Comment: Mesmo sem a fonte instalada?

Comment: faltou explicar que na hora de criar o executável é necessário indicar uma pasta com todos os recursos que serão embutidos no executável, inclusive a fonte. A forma de acessar a fonte pelo código muda um pouco também - veja a documentação do pyinstaller